# Columns in bootstrap 3.0 only stacking vertically

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

A real Web design newbie here. I've tried plenty of places online for an answer to this (including here) but to no avail. 
I'm trying my hand at a basic grid in bootstrap 3. My columns only stack vertically, they won't sit side-by-side, and they always resize to fill the browser window. This happens in Chrome or Firefox on desktop, and the same thing happens on chrome on my mobile devices (7 inch or 4.7 inch). 
FYI, I've just been editing with Sublime 2 and keeping all the bootstrap files under a folder in explorer. Not sure if that's relevant.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <!-- Bootstrap -->
       <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<style>
    .col-xs-12{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .col-xs-6{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
</style>
</head>
```

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">col-xs-12
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
     <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
   </div>
      </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Sorry about the terrible code formatting, it's hard to do this on the only device I have handy while on holiday - my 7 inch tablet!

Comment: Your code works as expected here: http://bootply.com/84307 -- Are you seeing any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code it seems is the references to

```
col-md-4
```

I ran a find/replace for all

```
-md-
```

and replaced it with

```
-xs-
```

and it seems to be working correctly with Twitter bootstrap.
See this JSfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jdSF3/
The Body

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">col-xs-12
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">col-xs-6
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
     <div class="col-xs-1">.col-xs-1</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-8">.col-xs-8</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
     <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
   </div>
      </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The CSS

```
  .col-xs-12{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .col-xs-6{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
  }
```