# Bootstrap columns are not appearing side by side and are all the same width

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently encountering an issue with incorporating Bootstrap 3 on my Rails 4.0.5 application. The server behind it is an Apache server. The Rails server being used is Webrick. I'm having extreme difficulties with the gem installations of twitter-bootstrap-rails, bootstrap-sass and Zurb Foundation thus I am going the route of native file incorporation.

I currently have bootstrap.js in app/assets/javascripts and bootstrap.css in app/assets/stylesheets. For all I know, these two are the only files required to run Bootstrap in general. The application calls for those two scripts in index.html.erb shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap 3.0 Grid System</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="/assets/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/assets/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <style>
    [class*="col-"] {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h3>Three equal columns</h3>
  <p>Get three equal-width columns <strong>starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops</strong>. On mobile devices, tablets and below, the columns will automatically stack.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what appears when I boot up the Apache server and the rails server then open up the application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGwUQ.jpg

As per this question: [Columns in bootstrap 3.0 only stacking vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113192/columns-in-bootstrap-3-0-only-stacking-vertically)

I tried changing all of the -md- to -xs- and that accomplished nothing at all.

In addition to that, the sizes are completely inaccurate. Any size column simply takes up the full width minus the padding.

I tried using the CDN method for hosting Bootstrap which made the application look right but due to security/maintenance issues I would much prefer to keep the files internal.

What I'm wondering at this point is if I did in fact do everything for Bootstrap correctly but the routing is causing the code within index to be read as plain HTML/CSS instead of actually importing the Bootstrap files from the assets directory. In the logs, I see

**Started GET "/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css" for (snip) ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css")**

Similar thing for bootstrap.js, application.css and application.js

I'm not sure what to do in this particular situation.

Another possibility is that I got my hands on a bad version of Bootstrap (got it from the Bootstrap download that had a Dist folder in it)

I had a suggestion from an acquaintance about using Alias on the Apache server to point towards a central location for those files but I don't know if this would work for Rails specifically.

Any ideas? I'll gladly provide more code snippets if requested.

As requested: application.html.erb in app/views/layouts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrapapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Perhaps I need to change the stylesheet_link_tag and the javascript_include_tag to point towards the Bootstrap files and clear this turbolinks stuff since I don't have the gem included on this particular project.

EDIT: Replacing the current stylesheet and javascript tags with

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap"%>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "bootstrap"%>
```

did not change the screen at all even after a reboot of the servers.

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

# Use DB2 as the database for Active Record
gem 'ibm_db'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'

# possible conflict with bootstrap
# gem 'haml'
```

I'm thinking maybe I need to add in the sprockets gem and whatever else is needed by the asset pipeline in order to fix this.

Comment: Rest of bootstrap styles are working for you? Did you download correct version of bootstrap? In your case it should be version 3 as you are using col-md-*

Comment: Yes, I have Bootstrap v3.2 downloaded from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download. I slapped together a quick Navbar from the sample templates on their site and that did not show up properly either. Inspect element in browser does indicate 404's being returned for the css and js files so I suspect that's the main issue here.

Comment: Rest of bootstrap styles are working for you? Can you post your layout file?

Comment: The file in app/views/layouts? I'll edit the main post with that momentarily.

Comment: Yeah you are using that file as your layout right?

Comment: Just saw your edited version. In your view you have `<link href="/assets/bootstrap.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />` but in your **layout you are using application.css**. I don't think you are using layout file for this template. Where did you add that link to add your bootstrap file?

Comment: I'm fairly new to Rails, I don't know the exact answer to that question because I typically do all of my HTML/CSS in the views. On a related note, I swapped in "stylesheets/bootstrap" and "javascripts/bootstrap" for the contents of the tags and refreshed. Didn't change anything for me.

Comment: okay checkout this for layouts http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#structuring-layouts Is this all of your layout file? Can you post your view as well?

Comment: Here's a key thing from that layouts link you gave me: The request to this asset is then served by the Sprockets gem. Might this be it? Adding an edit to reflect on this.

Comment: The view I think you're talking about is the one in the first code block of the question. index.html.erb. Yes, that is the entire layouts file application.html.erb you are seeing there.

Comment: I don't use RoR, so maybe there's an alternate way to do this I'm not seeing, but for what I see, you're not loading the most vital part of any Bootstrap deployment: Jquery

Comment: If you solved this, could you please post your solution as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found! I didn't want to be one of those guys who marked the question as resolved but not let anyone know what exactly I did so here's what I did. I went back and looked at another project of mine where I had successfully separated the CSS file from the html for readability purposes and found my answer there. What I had to do is drag the contents of the assets folder(stylesheet and javascript folders) from app/assets and put them into the app/public folder. Then I updated the stylesheet and javascript include tags within the view to point at "bootstrap" so it could find the files within the public directory. This method allowed me to bypass the need for the assets pipeline gems that were giving me so much trouble and also eliminated all of the route match errors I was getting in the console log on every request.

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout file to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrapapp</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
      <%= yield %>
    </body>
  </html>

#index.html.erb
<div class="container">
  <h3>Three equal columns</h3>
  <p>Get three equal-width columns <strong>starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops</strong>. On mobile devices, tablets and below, the columns will automatically stack.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

*Make sure your bootstrap.css file is inside app/assets/stylesheets and bootstrap.js inside app/assets/javascript directories. What we are doing is we are loading your css and js files from app/assets/stylesheets/application.css and app/assets/application.js files and if you open these files, lets say you open application.css, you'll see you have:*

```
*= require_tree .
```

***This line basically tell rails to load all the files inside app/assets/stylesheets directory, same goes inside application.js file.*** For details checkout [`Rails Asset Pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives). You should also checkout [**`Rails Tutorial on how layout and template works`**](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages)

Comment: Doing this just causes the CSS to show up twice with a #index.html.erb as plaintext between the two sets of stacked columns. Is this answer dependent on having already installed the gems for the asset pipeline? I have yet to do that.

Comment: @johnpurtle you don't have to install any gem. Read the links I gave you