# Columns using bootstrap grid system keep stacking vertically instead of in one row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <title>Column Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">a</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">b</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">c</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">d</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">e</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">f</div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">g</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">h</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">i</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">j</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">k</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">l</div>
        </div>
            </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

The code inside the body tags was taken from some website as an example of the Bootstrap grid system. It works when pasted into w3school's try it yourself editor for bootstrap. When I try to run the entire html file in Chrome, however, the row elements are all stacked vertically. Is there something fundamentally wrong with the syntax in some other part of the html file? Or is there something about the syntax of bootstrap's grid system itself that I'm missing?

A similar question was asked about a year ago: [Columns in bootstrap 3.0 only stacking vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113192/columns-in-bootstrap-3-0-only-stacking-vertically)
This single answer to this question has to do with switching md with xs, but I am using a 13 inch MacBook Pro, so md should do the trick. Anyway, I already have tried using the different sized col classes, so this is clearly not the problem.

Comment: Missing the viewport tag: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview

Comment: I put bootstrap.css in the project's css folder. Do I need to refer to other css files provided by bootstrap?

Comment: I put <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> in the head as it says in the documentation. This did nothing. Is this what you meant by missing the viewport tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use span[#of columns] instead of col-md-[#of columns].