# Ruby on Rails - Bootstrap - Columns not stacking Horizontally

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I've been experiencing some problems trying to create columns for Rails using bootstrap. I installed bootstrap with "[Integrating Rails and Bootstrap, Part 1 - the Installation](https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1)". This is what I have so far:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css" />
  </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main-container" class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div id="A_Name_Title" class="col-md-6" style="background-color: LightSteelBlue">
      <p>Test</p>
     </div>
    <div id="A_Time_Spent" class="col-md-6" style="background-color: LightSteelBlue" >
     <p>Test2</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

In the code, I am trying to create two columns stacked horizontally so I can use them as titles for the following rows. However, when I run the code I get:

[image]

I tried "[Columns in bootstrap 3.0 only stacking vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113192/columns-in-bootstrap-3-0-only-stacking-vertically)" but I still could not get it to work.

I am using Rails 5.0.1 with Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Ruby 2.2.6.

**Edit - 02-16-17 - 5:00 PM**

Moved the header into the correct place. Tried changing the "href="bootstrap.css" to "href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css" but RubyMine complained about that. Ignoring the complaint, the result was still the same. Followed the tutorial that @Fabrizio linked to and I still could not get it to work. With @Fabrizio's code, by replacing my link code with

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

I do get the result I want but from what I understand, if that website goes down, I lose access to the bootstrap.css

This is what I have for my "application.css.sass" file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

**Edit - 02/18/17**

Turns out I was having issues with coffee script and by adding "gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'" and then running bundle install, I was able to import bootstrap through the use of the sass gem and the application.html.erb file. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: please post the selectors' code "A_Name_title" and "A_Time_Spent"

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap css files in your html? Just checking, because the HTML you posted doesn't have it.

Comment: @venky I do not have any selector codes for those ids. I was under the assumption you needed them since the example in the tutorial had them.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL have the bootstrap.css file in the stylesheets folder. Do I need to specifically include it in the html?

Comment: @VectorConvoy Yes, you need to specify in your html that you need the bootstrap css with a `link`, example: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to your css file" />` otherwise your browser won't load it. You can have tons of files in the folder but browser will only load the ones you refer to in the html.

Comment: @raphaelDDL I added a header with the link to the bootstrap css file. Is that correct? If so, I still get the same result.

Comment: @VectorConvoy The correct way should be of the `head` inside `<html>`, before `body`. Also, you said is in a stylesheet folder, so the path (only `bootstrap.css`) looks incorrect, no? Shouldn't it be `stylesheets/bootstrap.css`? The point is. You need the css file imported with `link` in your html in order for the classes on it to be available to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you can load css files with Ruby on Rails without following the Asset Pipeline, basically you will have an application.css file inside app/assets/stylesheets, the html file should have this manifest file in the head tag with the following syntax 
`<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => "reload" %>`instead of 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path to your css file" />`
The manifest file application.css will include link to all the css files with the following syntax:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Additionally with Rails you can include Bootstrap with a gem, it is called `bootstrap-sass` and you can follow the instructions at https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Just include the gem as by the instructions in your Gemfile, run bundle install and then include it in your application.css..

Hear your can read about the asset pipeline. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

I included your css in my text editor and this is the result I get, two vertical columns, for me a red and blue column. I think this is the result you would like to reach with a col-md-6?

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div id="A_Name_Title" class="col-md-6" style="background-color: LightSteelBlue">
      <p>Test</p>
     </div>
    <div id="A_Time_Spent" class="col-md-6" style="background-color: red" >
     <p>Test2</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything seem good, if nothing works out, try creating new file 
`custom.scss in app/assets/stylesheets`
 and move the contents from application.css to custom.scss.
Also check the css selectors you used don't override any styles.